# Video Streaming Android special

Tags: android, streaming, android-videoview

In my Android app, I need to stream video online from URL ex: [demo](http://xemtvhd.com/xemtvhd/danang2.php).
I used Vitamio but it does not work well. Please help me to solve this problem (I need some suggestions or tutorials).

This is Logcat:
[image Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Foia.png)

Comment: whats the problem? what your logcat says?? please give a brief...

Comment: Post related code along with log cat if you get errors

Answer (score 0):

You use Video View in XML File

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/VideoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

in java file you use this code

```
String VideoURL ="Your Video Link...";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the layout from video_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.videoview_main);
    // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    // Execute StreamVideo AsyncTask

    // Create a progressbar
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoViewActivity.this);
    // Set progressbar title
    pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming Tutorial");
    // Set progressbar message
    pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // Show progressbar
    pDialog.show();

    try {
        // Start the MediaController
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                VideoViewActivity.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
        // Get the URL from String VideoURL
        Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
        videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoview.setVideoURI(video);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    videoview.requestFocus();
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        // Close the progress bar and play the video
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            videoview.start();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: i dided but:
Link 1: (http://static.bongdaplus.vn:8080/Media/2015/04/22/5/barca22042015a.mp4) it played very good!
Link 2: (http://xemtvhd.com/xemtvhd/danang2.php) it not worked!
Why ? Logcat above,

Comment: Hey Mr @Shine You try to wrong file to play File Like danang2.php file its not video file.

Comment: yes, but it is stream video online. What solutions ? Tks.

Answer (score 0):

you try to play video file in webview.
in xml File

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

in java file on create

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    startWebView("http://xemtvhd.com/xemtvhd/danang2.php");
```

this is method

```
private void startWebView(String url) {

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        // Show loader on url load
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                        ForgotPassword_Activity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });

    // Javascript inabled on webview
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Load url in webview
    webView.loadUrl(url);

}
```

i try this but at a load time i get the response is "Error Loading Player: No Playbale Sources Found.

Comment: @Shine when i try this i get in webview Error Loading Player: No Playable Sources Found.

Comment: Yes, i did so. I has idea: call onConfigurationChanged() but not working.